# Connection failed elastic search python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Elastic search connection fails. Curl works with fsSL option only.
 `curl -fsSL "http://elasticsearch_client_docker/"`  gives the following output:

```
  "name" : "ea241d36b96a",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "kcCzza3iQFWxnCv6Fz4zFg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.1.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "7a013de",
    "build_date" : "2019-05-23T14:04:00.380842Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.0.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

but with out -fsSL option, i get the following output:

```
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.13.8</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to connect to this elastic search using elasticsearch API in python. I keep getting the error: Connection Failed.

```
elastic_client = Elasticsearch(hosts=["http://elasticsearch_client_docker/"], use_ssl=True, verify_certs=True, ca_certs=certifi.where())
if not elastic_client.ping():
    raise ValueError("connection Failed")
```

Comment: Can you output `curl -i http://elasticsearch_client_docker/`

Answer (score 0):

Works by changing http to https.

```
elastic_client = Elasticsearch(hosts=["http://elasticsearch_client_docker/"], use_ssl=True, verify_certs=True, ca_certs=certifi.where())
```